# glBufferDataARB or glBufferSubDataARB?

Tags: java, opengl, vbo, lwjgl

I am developing a tile-based physics game like Falling Sand Game. I am currently using a Static VBO for the vertices and a Dynamic VBO for the colors associated with each block type. With this type of game the data in the color VBO changes very frequently. (ever block change) Currently I am calling glBufferSubDataARB for each block change. I have found this to work, yet it doesn't scale well with resolution. (Much slower with each increase in resolution) I was hoping that that I could get double my current playable resolution. (256x256)

Should I call BufferSubData very frequently or BufferData once a frame? Should I drop the VBO and go with vertex array?

What can be done about video cards that do not support VBOs?

(Note: Each block is larger than one pixel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should stop using both functions. Buffer objects have been core OpenGL functionality since around 2002; there is no reason to use the extension form of them. You should be using glBufferData and glBufferSubData, not the ARB versions.

Second, if you want high-performance buffer object streaming, [tips can be found on the OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). But in general, calling glBufferSubData many times per frame on the same memory isn't helpful. It would likely be better to map the buffer and modify it directly.

To your last question, I would say this: why should you care? As previously stated, buffer objects are *old*. It's like asking what you should do for hardware that only support D3D 5.0.

Ignore it; nobody will care.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware I was using non standard functions. I care about non VBO cards is I have an older laptop from 2000 or so that I was going to develop on.

Comment: It appears that LWJGL uses ARBVertexBufferObject as its default VBO.

Answer (score 3):

You should preferrably have the frequently changing color information updated in your own copy in RAM and hand the data to the GL in one operation, once per frame, preferrably at the end of the frame, just before swapping buffers (this means you need to do it once out of line for the very first frame).

`glBufferSubData` *can* be faster than `glBufferData` since it does not reallocate the memory on the server, and since it possibly transfer less data. In your case, however, it is likely slower, because it needs to be synced with the data that is still drawn. Also, since data could possibly change in any random location, the gains from only uploading a subrange won't be great, and uploading the whole buffer once per frame should be no trouble bandwidth-wise.

The best strategy would be to call `glDraw(Elements|Arrays|Whatever)` followed by `glBufferData(...NULL)`. This tells OpenGL that you don't care about the buffer any more, and it can throw the contents away as soon as it's done drawing (when you map this buffer or copy into it now, OpenGL will secretly use a new buffer without telling you. That way, you can work on the new buffer while the old one has not finished drawing, this avoids a stall).

Now you run your physics simulation, and modify your color data any way you want. Once you are done, either `glMapBuffer`, `memcpy`, and `glUnmapBuffer`, or simply use `glBufferData` (mapping is sometimes better, but in this case it should make little or no difference). *This is the data you will draw the next frame*. Finally, swap buffers.

That way, the driver has time to do the transfer while the card is still processing the last draw call. Also, if vsync is enabled and your application blocks waiting for vsync, this time is available to the driver for data transfers. You are thus practically guaranteed that whenever a draw call is made (the next frame), the data is ready.

About cards that do not support VBOs, this does not really exist (well, it does, but not really). VBO is more a programming model, rather than a hardware feature. If you use plain normal vertex arrays, the driver still has to somehow transfer a block of data to the card, eventually. The only difference is that *you* own a vertex array, but *the driver* owns a VBO.
Which means in the case of VBO, the driver needs not ask you when to do what. In the case of vertex arrays, it can only rely that the data be valid at the exact time you call `glDrawElements`. In the case of a VBO, it *always knows* the data is valid, because you can only modify it via an interface controlled by the driver. This means it can much more optimally manage memory and transfers, and can better pipeline drawing.

There do of course exist implementations that don't support VBOs, but those would need to be truly old (like 10+ years old) drivers. It's not something to worry about, realistically.